# how will you model a cityscape at night?

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]

I am really not able to imagine the backside of this picture i modelled the railings but cant move further so please help me by telling me what approach should i take to model this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend modeling the fence, vegetation and other props in the foreground.

Don't forget to get the grungy texturing right.

And the camera perspective, which can be captured easily using [Fspy](https://fspy.io/)<sup>*</sup> and its [official importer add-on for Blender](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender). It is not the only software camera matching software, but it is widely used.

Then, render it with alpha background, by ticking **Transparent** under Film settings.

After, choose the right background and just plug it in Photoshop or Gimp.

Then it's just post processing: Desaturation (Black and white) with high contrast. I'd further recommend going to [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/c/artwork/works-in-progress) "work in progress" and let your peer artists guide you through the rest to get a more accurate result.

---

*Note: The now standalone app [Fspy](https://fspy.io/) was previously [BLAM](https://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/23/blam-geometry-camera-matching-add-on/).

Comment: BLAM is an outdated version(used in old blender). He can use Fspy...

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Good call-out. I've edited that part of the answer to reflect current software.

Comment: [A search on Pixabay for city skyline night](https://pixabay.com/photos/search/city%20skyline%20night/) should provide some usable results for anyone looking to do this. If this needs to be animated in such a way that a simple image backdrop will not suffice, but actual modeling of a city is required, check out Gleb Alexandrov's tutorial [How to Create a City, Covered with Fog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1ROxTnD3E0).